# How to rearrange array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an assignment for school and i got a bit stuck in the process.

The idea is to make a program in C# where you can visualize how the insertion sorting algorithm works and for that I'm using an array of buttons with random generated numbers.

It colours green for comparison and red for swapping.

Why do the buttons remain coloured?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Button[] but; 
    int[] A;
    int nr_den = 0;
    int s1 = 0;
    int s2 = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nr_den = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
        s1 = Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);
        s2= Convert.ToInt16(textBox3.Text);
        A = new int[nr_den+1];
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 1; i <= nr_den; i++)
        {

            A[i] = r.Next(s1, s2);
        }

        but = new Button[nr_den + 1];

        for (int i = 1; i <= nr_den; i++)
        {
            but[i] = new Button();
            but[i].Text = A[i].ToString();
            but[i].Width = 40;
            but[i].Height = 40;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(but[i]);
        }
    }

    public  void exchange(int[] A, int m, int n)
    {
        string s;
        int temp;
        but[m].BackColor = Color.Red;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);
        but[n].BackColor = Color.Pink;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);

        temp = A[m];
        s = but[m].Text;
        A[m] = A[n];
        but[m].Text = but[n].Text;
        A[n] = temp;
        but[n].Text = s;

        but[m].Refresh();

        but[n].Refresh();
    }

    public  void sort(int[] A)
    {
        int i, j;
        int N = A.Length;

        for (j = 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            for (i = j; i > 0 && A[i] < A[i - 1]; i--)
            {
                but[i-1].BackColor = Color.Green;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);
                but[i].BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);
                but[i].Refresh();
                but[i - 1].Refresh();
                exchange(A, i, i - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i=1;i<=nr_den;i++)
        richTextBox1.Text += A[i]+ " ";

        richTextBox1.Text += " \n";

        sort(A);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
    }
}
```

[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1200V.png)

Comment: Instead of rearranging the buttons themselves, it would be easier to rearrange a backing array and just update the buttons after every pass.

Comment: If you put the thread to sleep it wont repaint what you just did

Comment: @Abion47 I'm sorting the A array but i don't know how to update the button array. the colouring is done by the position of thet button in the sorted array
*sorry for my english i know i'm not verry good at it

Comment: Ok i managed to update the buttons. Now the only problem is the colouring.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @JohnSmith As you can see here: http://i.imgur.com/mwK8zKL.png
why does the buttons remain coloured?

Comment: Because your code has not a single line that "uncolors" them

Comment: @JohnSmith Can you tell/teach me how to uncolour them? i was told thet the Button.Refresh(); method does that. and i tought it worked because there were no more green buttons.

Comment: [`Control.Refresh`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) redraws the control. To "uncolor" a button, set its `BackColor` to the original one which is `SystemColors.Control`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

restore color after completion

```
public void sort(int[] A)
    {
        int i, j;
        int N = A.Length;

        for (j = 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            for (i = j; i > 0 && A[i] < A[i - 1]; i--)
            {
                but[i - 1].BackColor = Color.Green;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);
                but[i].BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);
                but[i].Refresh();
                but[i - 1].Refresh();
                exchange(A, i, i - 1);
                but[i-1].BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
                but[i].BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            }
        }
    }
```

restore color during process

```
public void sort(int[] A)
    {
        int i, j;
        int N = A.Length;

        for (j = 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            for (i = j; i > 0 && A[i] < A[i - 1]; i--)
            {
                but[i - 1].BackColor = Color.Green;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);
                but[i].BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);
                but[i].Refresh();
                but[i - 1].Refresh();
                exchange(A, i, i - 1);
                but[i-1].BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
                but[i].BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);
                but[i].Refresh();
                but[i - 1].Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you verry much! I really apreciate your help!